# iOS Swift: Hide and unhide Nav and tool bars

Tags: ios, swift

Experts,

I am using following code to hide the tool and nav bars before capturing the screen view. However the image still shows both bars...what I'am I doing wrong?

```
func generateMeme() ->UIImage {
        // Hide toolbar and navbar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true

        // Render view to an image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.frame,afterScreenUpdates:true)
        let memedImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // Show toolbar and navbar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true

        return memedImage
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not doing a screenshot, but I had a similar need - I have a viewController with a UIToolbar at the bottom that I wanted to hide sometimes. I created an outlet to it; and used

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!


// later in the code where you don't want it visible anymore
toolBar.isHidden = true
```

but then there was still space allocated for the toolbar at the bottom of the window; and if the item in the scrollView it was next to was large enough it was really obvious that there was still something there blocking space.

I solved this by selecting the toolbar, and using Embed -> Stack View. Make sure and adjust the constraints of the stackview, setting each top, bottom, left and right to 0.   now the same line of code will hide the toolbar, and because it's in a UIStackView, it no longer takes up any space.

[image: Hierarchy Info]

You should be able to do the same; hide the toolbar, then snap the image.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.1**

Hiding the toolbar will be

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using reference outlet and then using the hidden property. Below is the code:

```
// Reference outlet for Tool Bar
@IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!

//Reference outlet for Navigation Bar
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

//Generate meme
func generateMeme() ->UIImage {


    // Hide toolbar and navbar
    self.toolBar.hidden = true
    self.navBar.hidden = true

    // Render view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let memedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Show tool and nav bars
    self.toolBar.hidden = false
    self.navBar.hidden = false


    return memedImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this(below) line at specific place in your code after that
 your toolBar will be removed permanently:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func getScreenShot() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            return image
        }
```

This should hide the navigationbar and toolbar. You can find the image in the Photos.

Comment: Try to clean your project. I have a navigation bar also but its not capturing the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had been exactly in the same problem and I tried your solution but the wrong was that , I suppose you were trying to address the default navigation controller built in toolbar while you need to address your own toolbar that you created in the story board.  I solved the problem as follow

1. create an outlet from my toolbar to the view controller

```
     @IBOutlet weak var toolbarView: UIToolbar!
```

2. make it hidden

```
 self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
 self.toolbarView.isHidden = true
```